# Integration involving Hermite polynomials

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, polynomials

I having trying to evaluate Integrate[Exp(-x^2 - k x) Hermite[n,x]Hermite[m,x], {x,-Inf,Inf}] without any success. Does anyone know either how to do it or what is the result of it? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The integration for orthogonal polynomials doesn't work in general. I would suggest writing to Support so that they make fixing it a priority.

Comment: I already did that, but someone expert in polynomial integrations in this forum might just know the result of Integrate[Exp(-x^2 - k x) Hermite[n,x]Hermite[m,x], {x,-Inf,Inf}] that would greatly help my current research work whilst waiting for Mathematica to take of the bug.

Comment: The integral can be evaluated by hand, I believe, if that would help.  One approach might be to complete the square of the argument of `Exp`, then expand terms involving H(x+y) using formulas given in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik or in Magnus & Oberhittinger, etc.  Use Mathematica to check your hand calcs, especially your final result.  When you substitute numbers for m & n, Mathematica will evaluate the integral.